# Group by clause not allowing grouping on class level

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have the following class but I want to use it within a LINQ group expression but I am hitting an error.

```
namespace importService.Model
{
 [DelimitedRecord(",")]
 [IgnoreEmptyLines()]
 public class Import
 {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductType { get; set; }
    public Single? Weight { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string NominalCode { get; set; }
    public decimal Costings { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; set; }
    public string ImportedBy { get; set; }
    public string OrderUser { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public long OrderNo { get; set; }
 }
}
```

I am trying to use it as following to group them nicely in an email

```
List<Import> orders = new List<Import> 
orders=Filled in from select statment from dapper
orders = orders.GroupBy(g => g.OrderNo).ToList();
```

However, I am getting the following error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
 Error  CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type > 

System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<long,

ImportService.Model.Import>>' to

'System.Collections.Generic.List<ImportService.Model.Import>'
```

How do I properly construct the group by query in this case?, I am using dapper to fill my orders element so it's getting filled ok it's just not wanting to allow the group.

**Aim**
My Aim is so that I can send an email shot based of the order numbers in the class and show a total row at the bottom of the email for each different order number.

It should be one email one email, where each total come after the rows for each set of OrderNo

```
foreach (var item in orders)
{
  using (var tr = table.AddRow(classAttributes: "someattributes"))
  {
         tr.AddCell(item.OrderNo.ToString(), "style:font-bold;");
         tr.AddCell(item.ProductName.ToString(), "style:font-bold;");
         if (item.Status == (int)ImportStatus.NominalInvlaid)
         {
               tr.AddCell("Nominal Code Invlaid");
         }
         tr.AddCell(item.Costings.ToString(), "style:font-bold;");
         tr.AddCell("DB", "style:font-bold;");
        }
```

This should display at the bottom of the lines above which should be group by the order no

```
  using (var tr = table.AddRow(classAttributes: "someattributes"))
        {//this should be the total of item.costings a the bottom of the above
        tr.AddCell(TotalOrdervalue.ToString(), "style:font-bold;");
        }
   }
```

Comment: A GroupBy creates a two dimensions array ; List<key, List<object>>.  You are trying to cast <key,List<object>> to List<object>

Comment: @jdweng It's actually an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<long, Import>>` where each item in the enumerable has a `Key` of type `long` and is itself a `IEnumerable<Import>`.  So the result of the `ToList` is a `List<IGrouping<long, Import>>` which is not the same as a `List<Import>`.

Comment: Note that if all you want to do is order all the rows by the `OrderNo` into one `List<Import>` then you should do an `OrderBy` instead.  In fact you could just do that in the SQL you use in your dapper code.

Comment: So is this one email or one per `OrderNo`?  If one email, are all the totals at the bottom or does each total come after the rows for each set of `OrderNo`?

Comment: @juharr each total come after the rows for each set of OrderNo that is correct.

Comment: @juharr do no how to solve this then Juharr?

Answer (score 1):

That's because the result of the group by isn't a list of  imports, instead it's a collection of lists.

try using the code below and see if it's working

```
var groupedOrders = orders.GroupBy(g => g.OrderNo).ToList();
```

an example of for loop would be

```
foreach (var og in groupedOrders)
                {
                    foreach (var item in og)
                    {
                        ...your code
                    }
                }
```

Comment: So it would be better having a query that did that on the dappe side ? or is their a way to make it a list

Comment: but that doesnt allow me to access each element in a for loop then ? based on the class

Comment: @rogue39nin, you should write a nested loop instead

Comment: @rogue39nin If you do a group by it means you want to have collections of rows grouped together.  It sounds like maybe all you really need is an `OrderBy`.

Comment: @juharr I am sending an email shot of order lines and order tototals so i want the email to bake on the order number during my for each

Comment: @rogue39nin In that case you'd take the result of the `GroupBy` and `foreach` over it and you'd have an item that has a `Key` that is the `OrderNo` and is an `IEnumerable<Item>` so you'd just need to create each email accordingly at that point.